# JavaScript basics

Tags: javascript

```
function Add(a, b) {      }
```

If we call a javascript function like -  `onclick="Add(1)"`

Why do we don't get error even though we pass only a single parameter or even more than 2 parameters (in case of above example) to function ?
How Java script treats above scenario?

Comment: Because Javascript ignores excessives parameters and sets to `undefined` the non-passed parameters

Comment: excessive parameters are still available through the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object.

Comment: @nitendra: don't forget that an important part of SO is accepting answers if they are correct and helpful... I see that you have 6 questions without accepted answers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is a dynamic, weakly-typed language. As a result, it doesn't strictly enforce method signatures.

`Add` is a Function object. It has a property called `arguments` which is an array-like object that contains the parameters that you pass in. As a convenience, it will also create local variables called `a` and `b` and assign the first and second elements in `arguments` to them. In the case where you only have one input parameter, `b` will be undefined.

So, Javascript will treat

```
 Add(1)
```

and

```
 Add(1, undefined)
```

as almost identical. The difference here is that the `arguments` variable will be of length 2 instead of 1. From a purely pragmatic standpoint, though, they're pretty well the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the concept of **Hoisting** in Javascript. Before the actual execution of your Javascript code, the parser runs through your code and it recognises where you have created the functions and where you have created the variables. Before your code begins to be executed by Javascript Engine - line by line, the Javascript engine already sets aside spaces in memory for the variables and functions written in the code. So, all the variables and functions are already made available in memory before your code execution begins. So, we will have access to them in a limited way.

When the Javascript Engine finds a function in your code, it sets up a memory space and places the entire function definition in it.

But, when it finds a variable in your code, it sets up a memory space; give it the name of the variable and sets a placeholder i.e. ‘undefined’ as its value (instead of the actual assigned value).

Please, have a look at the link below to have a better understanding of what is happening -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting